# Inkscape: How to evenly distribute lines within a rectangle?

Tags: inkscape, alignment, distribute

I'm new to Inkscape.

I want to align/uniformly distribute vertical lines within a rectangle. So that the space between the lines is all the same distance.

For example, if I have a 300x400 pixel rectangle and 4 lines, I want to distribute them with same distance inside the rectangle, but I couldn't do. Instead, they were aligning with each other. I put my output below.

[image]

Comment: Not certain I understand. So, you want the vertical lines to be evenly distributed within the enclosing rectangle?

Comment: Yes, what you say is right. I wanted to do it, but I couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following:

1. Now you have this:
   [image]
2. Turn on snapping, and add 2 more lines at the ends of rectangle:

[image]

3. Distribute 6 lines:

[image]

4. Finally, remove helpers:

[image]